# Open or Closed Sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $Q = {(x_1},x_{2},0) : x_{1},x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ be the $x_{1}$-$x_2$ plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is $Q$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I was thinking it would be sufficient to say that $\mathbb{R}^d$ is open since if we choose any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, then $B_r(x)$ ⊆ $\mathbb{R}^d$ for every $r > 0$ , so $\mathbb{R}^d$ is open?

Comment: Think about a Ball around (0,0,0) with radius $\varepsilon$. Is such a ball a subset of Q if $\varepsilon$ is small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you misunderstood the question whether $Q$ is open $\mathbb{R}^3$.

You write

> $\mathbb{R}^d$ is open since if we choose any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, then $B_r(x)$ ⊆ $\mathbb{R}^d$ for every $r > 0$ , so $\mathbb{R}^d$ is open.

This is correct, but it only says that $\mathbb{R}^d$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^d$ which is trivial. Your question deals with a specific subset $Q$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and asks whether it is open $\mathbb{R}^3$.

It is not, since each ball $B_r(x)$ with $x \in Q$ contains the point $x + (0,0,\frac r 2)$ which does not belong to $Q$.